# iOS開発でどうすればフレームワークにフレームワークを入れ込むことができますか？

Tags: swift, ios, macos, objective-c, framework

iOSであるライブラリ（フレームワーク）を開発しています。(Bとする）
このフレームワーク中に、別のフレームワークを入れたいと思います（別のフレームワークをCとする）
しかし、Bをビルドしてホストに入れようとしたら下記のエラーが発生していました（ホストアプリをAとする）

`dyld[932]: Library not loaded: @rpath...`

簡単に言うと　`B <- C` -> `A`

いくつかのサイトを参照しましたが解決案が見つかりませんでした、Static Libraryという実装方法があると聞いていますが、実際の実装方法は知っていません。

参照したサイト：

- [Static library inside iOS Framework error - Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/74213)
- [Static Library vs Dynamic Library - iOSエンジニアのつぶやき](https://yamatooo.blog/entry/2020/10/03/083000)

注：取り込もうとしているフレームワークを解体して自分の作ったフレームワークに入れることも可能です、フレームワークの作者とやり取りできますので。
ヒントでも良いですから、ご教授宜しくお願いします。

なぜフレームワークの中にフレームワークを入れるのかというと一個のフレームワークとして他人に提供したいと思っているからです。

ちなみにもらったフレームワークはbazelとかでビルドしているものでソースコードはありません。

Comment: 元のフレームワークを解体して利用も問題ないのであれば、そのフレームワークを単純に改変するではだめなのでしょうか？ / 「フレームワークの中にフレームワーク」がなぜ必要なのかをもう少し具体的に説明するとそれに応じた回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick ありがとう御座います、説明追加しました

Answer (score 2):

直接の回答ではありませんが、`iOS`のアプリケーションは、`Framework` in `Framework`だと審査段階で弾かれるという話を聞きました。
　なので、`Framework B`が`Framework A`を内包すると審査で弾かれてしまうので、`Framework B`の説明書きに`Framework A`もリンクする必要があると明記するのが正しい対処法だと思います。

コメントにあったフレームワークを解体して〜と言う話ですが、組み込むフレームワークのソースをプロジェクトとして入手し、そこに自分の作りたいフレームワークのソースを追加してコンパイルすれば良いと思います。逆に自分のプロジェクトにその人が作ったフレームワークのソースを組み込んでも良いです。いずれにしても、一つのフレームワークにまとめるには両方のソースが必用です。

Comment: よくわかないで聞いているんですが、Framework Aを解体してFramework Bに入れる方法はないですか？

Comment: つまりホストアプリは必ず２つのフレームワークをインポートしないといけないですか

Comment: - フレームワークを解体して別なフレームワークに組み込むことは可能だと思いますが、他人のソースの改ざんに当たりませんか？それだとメンテが非常に面倒くさい事になりそうですが

Comment: はい。ホストアプリは複数のフレームワークをインポートする必要があります

Comment: フレームワークを解体しても問題ないです、知り合いが作ったと思ってもらって良いです。ヒントでも良いです、その解体方法を教えていただけませんか

Comment: 回答に追記しました

Comment: 回答ありがとう御座います、事情よく説明していなくて申し訳ございません、向こうははbazelみたいなXCode以外のツールでフレームワークを作成したものです、そのままプロジェクトを手に入れられないと思います、フレームワークのフォルダだけは入手できます。

Comment: それは素直にフレームワーク2つをインポートする方が簡単だと思います。余談になりますが僕が作っているアプリは自作フレームワークを2つ、外部フレームワークを5つくらいインポートして作られています。それくらいは普通です